# Does Internet Explorer and Firefox support @media page?

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer, firefox

I've created a page with tables of data that I want to be big enough to view comfortably on the screen but when it goes to print I want it to shrink down to fit on the page but when I change the size of the table, td's and fonts it wont work, the code works in chrome but not the other two browsers.

```
@media print{

    .table6{
        page-break-inside: avoid;
        min-width: 500px;
        max-width: 900px;
    }

    .table6 td{
        font-size: 59.35%;        
    }

    .th7{
        max-width: 100px!important;
    }

    .th8{
        max-width: 28px!important;
        font-size: 58%;
    }
}
```

The CSS works the print css works but only on certain elements and using certain attributes like `display: none` to hide navigation links etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solved the issue, when changing the width inside of `@media print{}` it can't override the values which exist in the regular css which is suitable for the screen, even when `!important` is called on it so I put the css for my table inside `@media screen{}` and it worked.

So if anyone has this issue with changing widths heights or size in general when printing in other browsers make sure your css is split up into `@media print{}` and `@media screen{}` otherwise it wont work in IE or Firefox.

**(EDIT)**

In firefox also if you want something to appear on the screen one way and print another you MUST have your styles for on the screen in `@media screen{}` if you leave it in the normal css print styles will never override the regular css. For example I had this inside the normal css but it was ignored in firefox when printing

```
.table6{
    float: left;  
}
```

So I had to put it like this

@media screen{

```
.table6{
    float: left;
 }
```

}

Comment: Glad to see you solved the issue!  You should accept your answer.  Also, you should edit to say that you can't override values in IE and FF (but chrome allows it)

Comment: @Nirk thanks for the advice and help I will do as soon as it allows me I believe its 48 hours. Yeah I will also add the EDIT

Answer (score 2):

According to http://caniuse.com/#feat=css-mediaqueries, CSS3 media queries are supported as of IE9 and Firefox 23.0

Comment: Thats why I'm confused it does seem to work for certain elements of my page, like not displaying navigation links etc. I hate firefox and IE they're the most complicated to develop for. Chrome is effortless

Comment: @Crouch it might help to put up a sample page with some screenshots showing the issues

Comment: Basically the table is inside a wrapper it has a horizontal scrollbar to view across when it's width is more than the wrapper, when its on the page its big when its in google chromes print preview it shrinks based on the css rules but these rules aren't being followed by IE and Firefox and the table is just being cut off after so many columns.

Comment: It doesn't seem to like anything where I change the width, font-sizes it's okay with.

Answer (score 1):

whatever you need to check compatability for, i highly suggest:

http://caniuse.com/css-mediaqueries

hope that helps

Comment: Forgot to look on there I had been using that when checking html 5 compatability but yeah everything seems supported in the browsers I'm using which is concerning